# Locating opening page in Google Chrome Browser for Linux

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I use Ubuntu 14:04 LTS and when I fire up the Google Chrome Browser I want an opening pages set up with links of the 100 pages I use regularly.

How can I find that page on my desktop please?

Ampers.

Comment: If you're talking about that New Tab page Google Chrome has where it shows six websites you use frequently, then it's not an HTML flie. Also, what do you mean "on your desktop"? If you're trying to find it, how do you know it's on your desktop? If the New Tab page is not what you're talking about, then you need to make your question more descriptive. (A screenshot couldn't hurt.)

Answer (score 1):

Hi it's gona be a loong list isn't it!

Save your list as a HTML document.
Open your document in Chromium.
In the settings menue:
[image]

On Startup
Open a specific page.. Set Pages

Then choose Use current, Select the propper page.itl look something like this:

```
    file:///home/yourname/Documents/MyUrlList.html
```

- that should be your list with the 100 links.